# How to show attendance below the same date in table using php?

Tags: php

I create a monthly attendance report of students. I want to show present  and absent below the same date.

```
  <?php foreach ($status as $st): ?>
  <?php
  $date = date("d",strtotime($st['ats_date']));
    if ($dat['en_id'] == $st['en_id']) {
      // if ($st['ats_date'] != NULL){
        for ($row=1; $row <= 31; $row++) {
        if ($row == $date) {
          // code...

        if ($st['ats_status'] == 'Present' ) {

          echo "<th> P </th>";
        }
        elseif ($st['ats_status'] == 'Absent' ) {
          echo "<th> A </th>";
        }
        elseif ($st['ats_status'] == 'Leave' ) {
          echo "<th> L </th>";
        }
        else {
          echo "<th> H </th>";
        }
        }
          // }
          }
      }
     ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image]

I want this result

[image]

Comment: What is the data structure you are looping over here, please give an example of that.

Comment: (FYI, these are not table _header_ cells, but data cells - you should be creating `td` elements here, not `th`.)

Comment: You are creating a table cell for each `$row` (which should probably rather be named `$col` to begin with, because you are looping from 1 to 31 to create _columns_ here, not rows) value, right? But then why am I not seeing an `H` output in your screenshot, in the places where the status is not P, A or L? I don’t think the code you have shown matches the output.

Answer (score 0):

A few things in your code:

1) Not every month has 31 days. So you should use the last day of the month you are displaying as end number:

`$last_day = date('t', THE_MONTH_YOU_ARE_DISPLAYING );`

2) The `<th>` tag is for table headers. `<td>` is for table cells

3) As for your question, you could use an array filled with empty table cells for the row:
   `$array = array_fill( 1 , $last_day, '<td></td>');`

then in your code, determine the day of the month from the date, replacing the empty cell with **A, P, L or H**.

```
//get last day of month as maximum 
$last_day = date('t', $display-month );

//create empty array from 1 till last_day
$array = array_fill( 1 , $last_day, '<td></td>');

foreach ($status as $st){

    if ($dat['en_id'] == $st['en_id']) {
       //get the date of the record
       $day = date("d",strtotime($st['ats_date']));

       //determine the status
       if ($st['ats_status'] == 'Present' )$status = 'P'
       elseif ($st['ats_status'] == 'Absent' )$status = 'A'
       elseif ($st['ats_status'] == 'Leave' )$status = 'L';
       else $status = 'H';

       //replace the value on the exact day in the array with the status
       $array[ $day ]='<td>'.$status.'</td>';  
       }
//create table row
$student_status='<tr>'.implode('',$student_array).'</tr>';
echo $student_status;
```

**NOTE:** Code is not tested.